# Is geography trivia on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Finding GIS data for range of coast redwood?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76981) which was originally titled "**Giant tree, probably of America**" was closed as off-topic but was it really?

Sure it had nothing to do with GIS, but it was about geography, and it could be fun.

For the record yes, I voted to close it as well, just playing devil's advocate here.

Comment: That question would be closed whether or not it is considered on-topic (although it is not), because it shows a lack of research.

Comment: Have to agree with that, all of the information I supplied in my answer was just from Googling around...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vote for this Answer if you think such a Question should be considered **OFF-TOPIC**.

It may be a Question about Geography but this site is called the **Geographic Information Systems** (not Geography) **Stack Exchange**.

For reference, the text accompanying the photo in the original Question was:

> **Giant tree, probably of America**
>
> Where were such trees:
>
> This photo made in the 1800s...
>
> Is there any such tree?

Comment: That's nice but the [Geography Stack Exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37498/geography) was deleted. Probably because most of the geographers are here and not interested in splitting off into separate sites. I'm thinking it might fall under [Geoscience](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/geoscience) though.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up editing the original author's question heavily in order to make it on topic. Now it is about finding GIS data relating to the species in question.

Comment: That isn't an edit. Its a different (new) question with the same identifier.

Comment: It's rephrasing the question and including a tiny bit of research effort in the hopes of helping others in the future and not completely turning off a new visitor to our site.

Answer (score 2):

I have voted to keep it open (in the edited form of blah238). I can imagine interesting answers on how to find such data.

Apart from that I have very frequently seen closing requests recently where I thought: ok this may not be completely on topic, but is that really such a big problem? Questions which are widely interesting and in scope will get much more upvotes and more attention that way.